# JavaFX Checkbox TableCell setSelected

Tags: javafx-2, javafx-8

How can I .setSelected(true) to a Checkbox TableCell? This way it is checked when it appears. I have included my attempt below:

```
TableColumn decemberCol = new TableColumn();
decemberCol.setCellFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("december"));
decemberCol.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Month, Boolean>, TableCell<Month, Boolean>>() {
        @Override
        public TableCell<Month, Boolean> call(TableColumn<Month, Boolean> getSelectedProperty) {
            return new CheckBoxTableCell<>();     
        }
    });
ObservableList<Month> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();  
data.add(new Month(true));
```

...this then gets loaded into a tableView

Month class:

```
public Month(Boolean december){
     this.december = new SimpleBooleanProperty(december);
}

public Boolean getDecember(){
    return december.get();
}

public void setDecember(Boolean newValue){
    december.set(newValue);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the static method `CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(...)` which will return a `CheckBoxTableCell` bound (bidirectionally) to the cell value for the column. You probably also need to define a property accessor method in your `Month` class:

```
TableColumn decemberCol = new TableColumn();
decemberCol.setCellFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("december"));
decemberCol.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(decemberCol));
ObservableList<Month> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();  
data.add(new Month(true));
```

and

```
public Month(Boolean december){
     this.december = new SimpleBooleanProperty(december);
}

public Boolean getDecember(){
    return december.get();
}

public void setDecember(Boolean newValue){
    december.set(newValue);
}

public BooleanProperty decemberProperty() {
    return december ;
}
```

Comment: I think getDecember should be isDecember.

Comment: Either way works, though `isDecember` is more usual.